# How to display out of stock status for both simple product & configurable product in Product page magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have magento website that develop using 1.9 version and i need to display the out of stock status on product page for both simple product & configurable product

I have tried below method and It's only getting status of simple products

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
  $qty = $stock->getQty();
```

What i need is How to display the out of stock status for simple and configurable products in product page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me,
Hope this will help you.

```
if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ){
    if ($_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()<= 0) { ?>
    <span class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></span>
    <?php }else { ?>
    <span class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></span>
    <?php }; 
}
else{

    $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product);
    foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product) as $simple) {
        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();    
        $stockTotal = $stockTotal + $stock;
    }

    if ($stockTotal <= 0){ ?>
    <span class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></span>
    <?php } else{ ?>
    <span class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></span>
    <?php } 

}
```